# SAP BUILD: Can we copy a page from a different project to another project?

Tags: build, sapui5

I was able to copy a page or duplicate in the same project. But can we copy a page from one project to a different project?

Comment: Assuming you mean a .view.xml (or similar file), yes - it is possible. Not sure where your issue is. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SAP abandoned [SAP Build](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/02/04/sap-build-product-sunset/) completely. This question is less likely help future readers.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible. You just check namespance(controllerName="namespacename.pagename") name in the page if you are using xml view.

Comment: I'm sorry, to my knowledge there is no xml view in BUILD. If there is one please let me know how to access that.